# Magento 2 : Postcode / Zipcode and telephone number missing in checkout form

Tags: checkout, database, forms, magento-2.2.5

Have just tried to test the checkout form to ensure that my shipping methods are working and the postcode/zipcode and telephone boxes are missing in the checkout form.

[image]

After doing some research I've found that this may be due to missing information in the tables `eav_form_element` and `customer_form_attribute` but I'm unsure about how to fix this if this is the case.

Comment: Are you using some extension? For checkout

Comment: Amasty shipping table rates, rules and restrictions

Comment: Check if there ain't any settings of checkout fields or disable that extension and then check if missing fields appear again.

Comment: Are you using default luma theme ?

Comment: No. A custom version of the Infortis Ultimo theme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, basically this was some kind of database error.

think I've resolved it by restoring a backup file of the site from a time when I was not having this issue and then  and then restoring the more recent version without the database.

This seems to have fixed the issue but I can't be certain which of the tables in the database was causing it.

Answer (score 8):

Sometimes, while running our data migration it seems that the tables eav_form_element and customer_form_attribute lost some information during the migration.

The quick fix was to add in the missing postcode and phone number fields into the appropriate tables.

```
 INSERT INTO `customer_form_attribute` (`form_code`, `attribute_id`) VALUES 
 ('adminhtml_customer_address', '33'), ('customer_address_edit', '33'), 
 ('customer_register_address', '33'), ('adminhtml_customer_address', '34'), 
 ('customer_address_edit', '34'), ('customer_register_address', '34');


INSERT INTO `eav_form_element` (`element_id`, `type_id`, `fieldset_id`, 
`attribute_id`, `sort_order`) VALUES (NULL, '1', NULL, '33', '7'), (NULL, '2', NULL, 
'33', '7'),(NULL, '3', NULL, '33', '6'), (NULL, '4', NULL, '33', '6'), (NULL, '1', 
 NULL, '34', '9'), (NULL, '2', NULL, '34', '9'),(NULL, '3', NULL, '34', '8'), (NULL, 
 '4', NULL, '34', '8');
```

run these two queries into database, will fix the problem.

Happy Coding !!

Comment: Thank you, that will help a lot

Comment: your welcome!! @CJNotts

Comment: this happened to me too, 1.9.2.2 -> 2.4.2-p1; adding the attributes fixed it. Thanks mucho

Comment: BTW @RohitChauhan - do you have any idea which part of the migration causes this and why?

Comment: @grok_in_full its part of the attribute migration

Comment: @grok_in_full - it is because of customer attribute migration. you can check there.

Answer (score 1):

refer to this for some more info:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47022537/magento-2-checkout-missing-postcode

check the references to eav_attribute table in the tables mentioned in the answer above and add the indexes that you are missing.

for me this was also caused by migration, but not fixable with a backup.